# Como abrir uma nova janela para visualizar dados de uma tabela mysql via php?

Tags: php

Bom o que eu gostaria de fazer é o seguinte,
onde estou aprendendo php, fiz a página para visualizar os usuários cadastrado como campos nome e e-mail, e fiz um botão visualizar que vai chamar uma nova janela com todos os dados do usuário, o modo que aprendi é por tudo dinamicamente em uma única página, mas eu quero que ao clicar em visualizar abre uma nova janela como se fosse pop-up com todas as informações do usuário.

O que aprendi foi, colocar no botão visualizar o seguinte código:

```
<a href='administrativo.php&id=<?php echo $dado['op_id']; ?>'<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i></button></a>
```

Na página administrativo está:

```
<?php
$link = $_GET["link"];
$pag[1] = "visualizar.php";   
if(!empty($link)){
        if(file_exists($pag[$link])){
            include $pag[$link];
        }else{
            include "dashboard.php";
        }
    }else{
        include "dashboard.php";}?>
```

Então dentro da página administrativo ele me mostra as informações do usuário.

O que preciso é que ao clicar em visualizar me abre uma nova janela com todas as informações.

eu tentei mudar o código para:

```
 <a href='visualizar.php&id=<?php echo $dado['op_id']; ?>'<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i></button></a>
```

mas me retorna página não encontrada.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguinte:
Faltou o "?".

visualizar.php?id=
Segue:

```html
 <a href='visualizar.php?id=<?php echo $dado['op_id']; ?>'<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i></button></a>
```

Comment: heheheheh verdade :) Valeu Mesmo